# Azure monitor exporter with Golang

Tags: azure, go, open-telemetry, azure-monitoring, otel

I am currently trying to connect my Go application to Azure monitor, and I am facing issues right away with the "otel" contrib package (https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/exporter/azuremonitorexporter)

The exporter that I am trying to use does not implement the `ExportSpans` function for the interface `WithBatcher` needs in otel. I've searched the web for examples with Azure monitor and Go, but little comes up. We do have the `applicationinsights` package from Azure, and I have tested with with some manual traces, but I would like the exporter to work as well.

Has anyone tried this before? Am I doing something wrong or not understanding otel fully? Any pointers in the right direction would be great.

```golang
func initMonitor() (*sdktrace.TracerProvider, error) {
    key := os.Getenv("INSTRUMENTATION_KEY")
    exporterConfig := azuremonitorexporter.Config{
        InstrumentationKey: configopaque.String(key),
    }

    factory := azuremonitorexporter.NewFactory()

    azExporter, err := factory.CreateTracesExporter(context.Background(), exporter.CreateSettings{}, exporterConfig)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    tp := sdktrace.NewTracerProvider(
        sdktrace.WithSampler(sdktrace.AlwaysSample()),
        sdktrace.WithBatcher(azExporter),
    )

    otel.SetTracerProvider(tp)
    otel.SetTextMapPropagator(propagation.NewCompositeTextMapPropagator(propagation.TraceContext{}, propagation.Baggage{}))

    return tp, nil
}
```

I would like for the azuremonitorexporter to be added as a tracer provider form otel in Go to instrument my Go application.

Answer (score 0):

**Install the Required Packages:**

```
go get go.opentelemetry.io/otel
go get go.opentelemetry.io/otel/exporters/azuremonitorexporter
go get github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go@latest
```

- I have also installed `go get github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/exporter/azuremonitorexporter@latest`

[image]

**Configure the Exporter:**

In the application Go code, initialize the Azure Monitor exporter and configure it with your Instrumentation Key.

**code:**

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "os"

    "go.opentelemetry.io/otel"
    "go.opentelemetry.io/otel/exporters/azuremonitorexporter"
)

func main() {
    // Retrieve your Azure Monitor Instrumentation Key from an environment variable.
    instrumentationKey := os.Getenv("INSTRUMENTATION_KEY")
    if instrumentationKey == "" {
        log.Fatal("Please set the INSTRUMENTATION_KEY environment variable.")
    }

    // Create an Azure Monitor exporter with the specified Instrumentation Key.
    exporter, err := azuremonitorexporter.NewExporter(azuremonitorexporter.WithInstrumentationKey(instrumentationKey))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to create Azure Monitor exporter: %v", err)
    }

    // Set up the OpenTelemetry TracerProvider with the Azure Monitor exporter.
    tp := otel.NewTracerProvider(
        otel.WithBatcher(exporter),
    )

    // Set the TracerProvider as the global tracer provider.
    otel.SetTracerProvider(tp)

    // Your application logic here...

    // Ensure that telemetry data is flushed before the program exits.
    if err := tp.Shutdown(context.Background()); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error shutting down tracer provider: %v", err)
    }
}
```

- You can customize spans to gather telemetry data relevant to your application.

**Send Telemetry Data:**

- As your application runs, it will send telemetry data, including traces, to Azure Monitor for monitoring and analysis.

[image]

If you are open to use a different exporter for your tracing data, you might explore other OpenTelemetry exporters that are well-maintained and support Go applications. Some popular alternatives include exporters for Jaeger, Zipkin, and others.

Comment: Hm, how did you get go.opentelemetry.io/otel/exporters/azuremonitorexporter

The official repo doesn't have this package.

Comment: @chip, Check this both official website [azuremonitorexporter](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/exporter/azuremonitorexporter) and [exporters](https://pkg.go.dev/go.opentelemetry.io/otel/exporters)

Comment: @SureshChikkam Firstly your screenshot and code snippet don't match. 

Opentelemetry doesn't have "go.opentelemetry.io/otel/exporters/azuremonitorexporter" exporter. Here is the list of available exporters which will work with otel core - https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-go/tree/main/exporters

The "github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/exporter/azuremonitorexporter" completely different story, it is not compitable with otel core, it is used in otel collectors flow - https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector/blob/main/docs/design.md

Answer (score 0):

Otel contrib package (https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/exporter/azuremonitorexporter) is used in different flow. It is used for collecting data from processors and receivers (https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector/blob/main/docs/design.md).

In your case you want to use otel core as I see from your example. Here is the list of available exporters which will work with otel core - https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-go/tree/main/exporters

Some vendors can have their implementations not in otel repo but their own instead - https://opentelemetry.io/ecosystem/vendors/ As you will see at the moment Azure doesn't have any implementation which can be used with otel core.

One way to make it work is to use for example supported otel core exporters such as "otlpmetricgrpc" or "otlptracegrpc" which will send data to "otlpreceiver" and it will send the data to "azuremonitorexporter". This flow is way more complex than using otel core. Here is an example https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-go/blob/main/example/otel-collector/main.go

Another option is to use Azure Insights Go library (https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Go), but the downside that you will depend on vendor specific interfaces.